TWIG showing error upgrading Drupal 10 upgrade
TWIG code
{% if 'export' in url %}
<a href="{{ url }}"{{ attributes.addClass('btn btn-success') }}>
{{ '@format export'|t({'@format': 'Export files'},{'context': 
'kjus'}) }}

</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{{ url }}"{{ attributes.addClass('btn btn-success') }}>
{{ '@format csv'|t({'@format': 'CSV'},{'context': 'kjus'}) }}

</a>
{% endif %}

shows the following error

Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "(" ("end of print statement" expected). in Twig\TokenStream->expect()  
Not getting the error


Doesn't the error also mention the line?

It does mention from here
{{ '@format export'|t({'@format': 'Export invoices'},{'context': 'kline'}) }}
Though there was a missing ',' after the translatio filter but didnot work

The snippet looks syntactically correct. Did you try and clear the cache after the upgrade?
